# Как правильно читать объемные файлы состоящие из большого количества строк

Tags: java, arraylist

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прочитать из файла, содержащего больше 9 тыс. строк, заполненных 9 - 18 -значными числами. Пробую сразу выводить на печать и выходит только вторая половина, пробую записывать в лист и выводить - выходят только запятые.

```
public class RandomForest {
private static List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("d://forest.txt")));

        int c;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            chars.add((char) c);
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(chars.toString());
}

public class RandomForest {
private static List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://forest.txt"));
    String line;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

Comment: Читайте построчно с помощью метода `readLine`  - будет проще. И с конструкцией _try-with-resources_ ознакомьтесь - меньше кода придётся писать.

Comment: C readLine тоже пробовал побайтово читать...

Comment: А покажите ваш код, который с readLine, может в нём грубые ошибки.

Comment: Добавил второй код с readLine выше, записывает только первые 1055 строк в лист(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Комментарии по коду в вопросе автора:** в целом чтение больших файлов сделано правильно, то есть в потоке. И также не принципиально каким методом пользоваться `read()` или `readLine()`. Просто при `readline()` будут теряться спец-символы переноса строк из конкретного файла.

**Проблема в коде автора:** но архитектурная ошибка в том, что в коде большой файл пытается полностью загрузиться в память, в частности полностью сохраниться в `ArrayList<>`.

**Как рекомендуется обрабатывать файлы больших объемов:**

1. Работать в потоке/потоках.
2. При чтении, сразу же "на лету" выполнять обработку полученной информации, то есть не сохранять весь файл в память.

**Доработанный пример от автора вопроса:**

1. Удалили из кода объект `chars` и объект `lines`.
2. Сделали некую обработку каждой строки файла "на лету" через `MyOtherStaticClass.sendData()`.

public class RandomForest {

```
//private static List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://forest.txt"));
    String line;
    //List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //lines.add(line);
        MyOtherStaticClass.sendData(line);//здесь можно вызвать какой-нибудь сервис или записать данные в некий Output-поток и т.п.
    }
    System.out.println(lines);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, не сочтите за наглость, но был бы очень благодарен примеру реализации того, что написано выше. Можно буквально отрывками кода показать эти 2 пункта. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Обработку можете сделать любую, можно и сохранять часть считанных данных во внутренний объект, главное делать это порционно. Или сразу "на лету" обрабатывать.